# css: Cross-browser, reflowing, top-to-bottom, multi-column lists

Tags: internet-explorer, list, css

See http://cssfingerprint.com/about#stats.

See also [Multi-column CSS lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933645/multi-column-css-lists).

I want a multi-column list that:

- uses no JS
- reflows on window size

  - makes as many columns as fit the enclosing element
  - therefore, does not require batching the list into manual column groups
- works in all browsers
- works for an arbitrary number of unknown-width (but single-line-height) elements

  - makes each column fit the width of its (dynamic) contents
- does not create scrollbars or other overflow issues
- is sorted top to bottom where possible

My code is currently:

```
ul.multi, ol.multi {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 -moz-column-width: 12em;
 -webkit-column-width: 12em;
 column-width: 12em;
 -moz-column-gap: 1em;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
 column-gap: 1em;
}

ul.multi li, ol.multi li {
 <!--[if IE]>
  float: left; 
 <![endif]-->
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Although this works *okay*, it has some problems:

- I have to guess the content width
- it is right-to-left in IE (though this is acceptable as a graceful degradation mode)
- it won't work at all in non-IE, non-Moz/Webkit/CSS3 browsers

How can this be improved?

Comment: Is this code generated on the server or is it a static HTML page? If it's a dynamic page you could do the HTML formatting on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using CSS3 for any structural website design. My best guess is try something like below, essentially just removing the CSS3 stuff. The big issue here if I am understanding you correctly is not knowing the width of you items. With a fixed width something like this should be all you need, but for what you have described it looks like your going to need some help from our good old friend Javascript! : )

```
<style>
body, html
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.multi
{
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.multi li
{
    float: left;
    width:10em;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>

<ul class="multi">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I had before. It fails at being top-to-bottom, though. :-P

Comment: top to bottom... yeah, you definitely need javascript then to sort your data. It is certainly doable, but not without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not think this is possible in IE without some js or backend wizardry/hacking.  Here's a useful demo that provides a little bit of hackery:

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=27f87

But it's obviously not perfect.

OR with JS: http://www.cvwdesign.com/txp/article/360/multi-column-layout-with-css3-and-some-javascript

Again, your best bet is to do some math on the server and dish it up right, OR, if you are willing to forgo IE, utilize column-width or column-count, but that depends on what needs support.  Unfortunately, we're just stuck in the 80s still.  :p