# Putting a list into two columns in CSS

Tags: css, styling

I can't figure out how to get my list into a two column list. I tried some of the examples in other similar questions but it just doesn't change anything.

```
<div class="section" id="skillset">
<h1>SKILL SET:</h1>
<h2>Have passed classes which taught all of the following:</h2>
<ul class="skills">
    <li>Intermediate Spanish</li>
    <li>Microsoft Word</li>
    <li>Microsoft Power Point</li>
    <li>Microsoft Excel</li>
    <li>Dreamweaver</li>
    <li>Adobe Photoshop</li>
    <li>CAD Lab</li>
    <li>Visual Basic</li>
    <li>C++</li>
    <li>Java</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to have 5 items in the list then another 5 to the right of it.

Due in one hour :(

Comment: Use [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933645/multi-column-css-lists

Comment: Wait, the OP is in a hurry and gets some great answers and never marks one as the correct answer. Very nice.

Comment: Didn't know I was supposed to, I don't see that option but apologies.

Answer (score 14):

`column-count` can surely help you here.

Just add the following CSS

```
.skills
{
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 2.5em;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2.5em;
     column-count: 2;
     column-gap: 2.5em;
}
```

but do check the browser support as it will not work in older versions of IE

Here is a [**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/tMZ8Q/8/) of working code

Answer (score 3):

Inside your CSS code things, put this:

```
.skills {
/* other codestuff */
column-count: 2;
}
```

I hope this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

set li width 50% and 
display : inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the following css attributes to your `li` elements:

```
.skills li {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}
```