# Multi-column list in CSS

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to create a sort of columned list with just HTML and CSS. I have tried using floats, and inline-block, and it would seem as though inline-block is going to be my best bet, as I have the following requirements:

- The layout should be in columns;
- The number of columns should not be “preset”, but should be adaptive;
- The height of the columns must not be preset, but the width may be (if necessary).

The problem is that when the height of the list-items is not the same, you get gaps, whereas I want them to continue straight down.

I am using a structure something like this:

**CSS**

```
.columnlist li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class=’columnlist’>
    <Li><H6>List 1 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>List item 1</LI>
        <LI>2ND List Item</LI>
        <LI>Item in List 3</LI>
        <LI>Final Item</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 2 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Penultimate LI</LI>
        <LI>Final Constituant</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 3 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Opening  Movement</LI>
        <LI>Closing  Component</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 4 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Original Child</LI>
        <LI>2nd Element</LI>
        <LI>Then the 3rd</LI>
        <LI>And Last But Not Least</LI></UL></LI>
</UL>
```

Is there any way of removing the vertical space around the elements with CSS?

*Note:* I think something like this might work, but are there any other ways of doing such a thing?
[Multi-column CSS lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933645/multi-column-css-lists)

Comment: Sounds like CSS columns are your best bet, tho the order of the items will be different from float/inline-block.

Answer (score -1):

Before adding my CSS, let's look at your code:

```css
.columnlist li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<ul class=’columnlist’>
    <Li><H6>List 1 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>List item 1</LI>
        <LI>2ND List Item</LI>
        <LI>Item in List 3</LI>
        <LI>Final Item</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 2 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Penultimate LI</LI>
        <LI>Final Constituant</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 3 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Opening  Movement</LI>
        <LI>Closing  Component</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 4 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Original Child</LI>
        <LI>2nd Element</LI>
        <LI>Then the 3rd</LI>
        <LI>And Last But Not Least</LI></UL></LI>
</UL>
```

Now, look what happens when you add my CSS, all vertical space is removed and you have a 'column' for each level of list items:

```css
.columnlist li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
ul, li, h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class=’columnlist’>
    <Li><H6>List 1 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>List item 1</LI>
        <LI>2ND List Item</LI>
        <LI>Item in List 3</LI>
        <LI>Final Item</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 2 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Penultimate LI</LI>
        <LI>Final Constituant</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 3 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Opening  Movement</LI>
        <LI>Closing  Component</LI></UL></LI>
    <Li><H6>List 4 of 4</H3>
    <UL><LI>Original Child</LI>
        <LI>2nd Element</LI>
        <LI>Then the 3rd</LI>
        <LI>And Last But Not Least</LI></UL></LI>
</UL>
```

If you wanted to achieve something else please let me know and I will revise my answer.

Comment: Can you please clarify how this is going to help create a columnated list, minus the vertical whitespace? Your current answer (alone) just creates a list, and combined with my current code has no effect (on the vertical space). Thanks.

Comment: Check my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, it makes sense now. Unfortunately, it still does not achieve the desired result. I want the second level lists to still be vertical, but I want the top-level list below it on the next line to float up and fill the gap; hence the 4-2-2-4 pattern.

Comment: Alright, if you need anything else just reply. Don't forget to upvote :)